# Is there an ability to delegate contacts with the new contacts.google.com via API?

Tags: google-workspace

Just want to know if there is a way to do this yet. I went through their https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/ site to look for more info but I can't find anything on delegation.

To elaborate.

Due to legal issues, when we get requests for users to get "delegated access" to email. We use API calls to make the changes in order to not log into their accounts directly and make the changes. We have an API Call for email forwarding and email delegation, but we do not have one for contact delegation. Searching their site, i'm not finding how I would do that call.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to improve it.

Comment: I edited the post